# Can browse internet but can't update Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, internet, update-manager, ping

Using wifi connection or 3G connection I can access Internet but when I'm trying to install updates through the software updater it says no Internet connection. When I try *ping google.com* it also failed. 
But using browser I can surf Internet without any problem, I'm bored with this problem already, can any one please help me to solve this?

Comment: See my post here: http://askubuntu.com/a/707754/476968

Answer (score 0):

That sounds a lot like a proxy issue. Check if you are using a proxy to browse the internet (firefox or whatever browser you are using) and replicate the setting to your network proxy sttings of the system. You can also use thr /etc/environment file to setup the proxy by adding a line http_proxy entry . This will equally for for https_proxy and ftp_proxy. Or, if no proxy exist on browser, verify that system isn't using one as well. After changing this do a network restart.