# Proxy Authorization Required

Tags: networking, firefox, proxy

**I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS(64 bit)**

### Problem

I am not able to access internet due to failed proxy authentication process.
I have specified a proxy server in FireFox -> Network ->Manual.. As soon as I browse a website -> Firefox shows the following:

**"Proxy Authorization Required Description:Authorization is required to access the proxy"**

Is there any solution to get the pop window to enter the username, password to complete the authorization process ?

Additionally, Terminal also fails in updating the setup. It also shows "407 Proxy authorization required"

### What I have done so far

I have done the following:

1. Disabled the option "Block pop up windows" in the Firefox settings
2. Disabled firewall.
3. Put "username:password@proxyserver:portno/" in Network Proxy->Manual in Firefox.
4. Used Network Proxy->Use System Settings with the same format. in step 3.
5. Changed the default option to user options of many config parameters in firefox namely:

   - network.auth.force-generic-ntlm
   - network.auth.force-generic-ntlm-v1
   - network.automatic-ntlm-auth.allow-non-fqdn
   - network.automatic-ntlm-auth.allow-proxies
6. Changed the export parameters (environ. variables)for http_proxy, https_proxy etc to the same format specified in Step 3.

All the above specified steps fails.

### Additional Informations:

I have pinged the proxy server, it replies. So, the communication to proxy server happens.

**I've got no clue how to solve this issue.
Please reply at the earliest.**

Answer (score 1):

First off all, change the network settings from manual to automatic and leave the Firefox proxy setting set to manual.

For the terminal to work with your proxy, do the following: 
Create the following file :
 `/etc/apt/apt.conf`, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

Edit this file according to your proxy details:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://username:password@yourproxyaddress:proxyport";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://username:password@yourproxyaddress:proxyport";
```

If your proxy doesn’t require a username, then those statements take the following form:
Acquire::http::proxy yourproxyaddress:proxyport";

To be able to add [a PPA](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983/476968), you will need to export your proxy settings open the terminal and type:

```
export https_proxy="https://username:password@yourproxyaddress:proxyport";

export http_proxy="http://username:password@yourproxyaddress:proxyport";
```

Once you have done this, to export you will need to add a `-E` after `sudo`, e.g. `sudo -E apt-get install python-software-properties`